# remove python version 3.2.5

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have installed the python version 3.2.5 the latest bundle yesterday ,i would like to delete it

I have tried these things

```
THis is Mine:~ LRI$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2
THis is Mine:~ LRI$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2.5
THis is Mine:~ LRI$ sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python 3.2.5"
THis is Mine:~ LRI$ cd /usr/local/bin; 
THis is Mine:bin LRI$ ls -l . | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2.5' | awk '{print $9}' | xargs rm
THis is Mine:bin LRI$ python --version
Python 3.2.5
```

Still showing the current version as 3.2.5 
Also one thing i have noticed is in the

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
```

inside this next to 2.7 folder which i was using 
there is a new folder which is named as Current and there is a curved arrow around the folder at the bottom left (I think it is 3.2.5) i have installed 
I would like to know why it is named Current
Also i would like to know the solution to how can i switch back to 2.7,
because none of my python projects are not running now

Comment: What does `which python` show?

Comment: @DanielRoseman /opt/local/bin/python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed it by downloading the source then in your source directory there will be a make file and run "make uninstall" to uninstall it.

Why do you have to remove it? You can keep multiple versions right?

If you want to use python 2.7 by default then create a softlink of python 2.7 to /opt/local/bin/python and use it.

Comment: @daa I meant how to create a softlink of python 2.7 to /opt/local/bin/python?

Comment: You can create softlink like this from /opt/local/bin/python -> python2.7 using `ln -s `

Comment: @daa can you please elaborate with an example (by including version etc)please

Comment: Run the following command in your linux terminal ln -s path/to/python2.7/bin/python /opt/local/bin/python

Comment: CPython's Makefile doesn't have an uninstall rule. In Linux I have to use `checkinstall` to create a package. In OS X, Homebrew can uninstall a formula.